# Flask - How to populate select field in wtf form when database files is separated?

Tags: flask

I have separated model file and using app factory. The project structure is
like this:

```
project/
|-- config.py
|-- core.py      # app factory definition which calls db.init_app(app)
|-- database.py  # models definition and 'db = SQLAlchemy()' is done here
|-- forms.py     # forms definition.
|-- __init__.py  # app = create_app() is done here
\-- routes.py
```

I have two models: article and category. Then, in `forms.py`, I tried to do
like this:

```
class ArticleForm(Form):
    title = StringField()
    content = TextAreaField()
    category = SelectField(
        choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Category.query.all()]
    )
```

So, `Category.query.all()` is called outside app context and raising this:

```
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application
bound to current context
```

So, how can I populate the `SelectField` with existing data on database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use WTForms' [QuerySelectField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ext.html#wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField) extension:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from database import Category

class ArticleForm(Form):
    title = StringField()
    content = TextAreaField()
    category = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Category.query.all())
```

Answer (score 10):

This blog post helped me as I couldn't get the accepted answer to work like I wanted.  Gets rid of an import as well.

http://kyle.marek-spartz.org/posts/2014-04-04-setting-wtforms-selection-fields-dynamically.html

I used his second technique which for the question would look like

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField, TextAreaField
from database import Category

class ArticleForm(Form):
    title = StringField()
    content = TextAreaField()
    category = SelectField()

    def __init__(self):
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__()
        self.category.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Category.query.all()]
```

Comment: This syntax did not work for me, so I had to tweak it to be:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)